# a list of errors and exceptions that ELMAH catches and logs

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I tried to find a **list** of `errors` and `exceptions` that **`ELMAH`** can catch and logs but I couldn't . I wonder if **`ELMAH`** catches things like members **logins** or **failed logins** , **request** errors like `401` , `403` ,`404` and ... .

thanks in advance .

Comment: Are you wanting to NOT catch those? See the docs: http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering

Comment: @aquinas : no , I want to know if ELMAH catch this sort of errors or not , that sounds like it doesn't

Comment: No, as @Oded, says below, it catches EVERYTHING. You have to explicitly filter out things you don't want to catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default ELMAH will catch **all unhandled exceptions**.

You can also send ELMAH other exceptions that you wish (in your exception handler), but unless an exception was thrown and **not handled** it will not get logged by ELMAH.